# API call to render the output of an App (win) to a image

Tags: c#, .net, printing, screen, printscreen

I need a to build a application (.NET) that given the pid of another app continually makes printscreens of that app to make a video... I'm using the API call: 
new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

the problem I've is speed....

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need high speed capture you might want to check DirectShow api, so you can build a screen capture graph and save output as a movie (avi, wmv etc).. Some information on that you can find there: [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/).

You can check for example PlayCap example. What you need is screen capture source filter. (You can see [MediaLooks](http://www.medialooks.com/) or PushSourceDesktop from Windows sdk samples I'm sure there are more choices ..)